# Using VCS root with dependency parameters

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I've got a pipeline where differing sections use VCS roots that point at the same git repositories.

In making up a custom pipeline that allows the VCS root default branch to be set as a parameter (defaulting to master) I'd like downstream jobs to use the same branch, however the downstream appears to use the default regardless of how I override it using %deps%

Am I misunderstanding how paramaterised vcs roots work?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to setup [Snapshot Dependencies](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Snapshot+Dependencies) between all build configurations in your pipeline - you don't need to do parametrization of "default branch".

> use the same sources snapshot as the entire queued build chain being processed

in git it basically means that all build configurations in the pipeline will use the same commit, therefore the same branch as well

Comment: We use different vcs roots at different stages of the pipeline as the code is organised in small repos rather than having everything in one place.

Does the %dep.% get overridden somehow when we're talking about vcs roots?